# how to wait for websocket reply before allowing page to load in chrome extension contentscript?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, websocket

I'm working on a url scanner chrome extension. In contentscript (runat document_start), I send url to my websocket server and wait for returned verdict. However websocket messages are delivered in async way, thus page may be already loaded and displayed if network is slow. How can I call websocket in synchronous way and allow page loading only after verdict is received?

Comment: There's no way to do it in a Chrome extension. There are workarounds of varying ugliness and inconvenience for the user. Try making the request inside the background script in chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest so it happens long before the page is shown in most cases.

Comment: but blocking webRequest is not available in mv3.

Comment: It doesn't have to be blocking.

Comment: but i want to redirect to a blocking page when url is malicious, in this case blocking webRequest is necessary.

Comment: As I mentioned it is impossible generally.